# chase camera with FlyControls.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make a simple flight game with three.js and FlyControls.js

this is how I loaded the airplane.json:

```
objectLoader.load("obj/airplane.json", function ( obj2 ) {
scene.add( obj2 );
});
```

I cant force the airplane.json to follow the camera.(chasing camera)
I have tried several solutions but I got these errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

obj2 is not defined
```

it's my render section:

```
function render() {
controls.update( clock.getDelta() );
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
scene.traverse( function ( object ) {
if ( object instanceof THREE.LOD ) {
object.update( camera );
}
} );
var vector = camera.position.clone();
vector.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorld );
obj2.position.sub(vector, fixedPosition);
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use `obj2` out of scope. `obj2` is added as a scene, so you should be able to find it via `getObjectByName` of the `Object3D` class.